# I have a text file. I want search phrases like this format or with punctuation or like in jumbled word format. I use Python 3.x. Any python library

Tags: python, nlp

**Test1.txt**

.**Personal Information and Demographic Information**. On the Service, we may ask you to provide us with certain categories of information such as: (1) **Personal Demographicinformation**, which is information that identifies you personally, such as your first and last name, e-mail address, mailing address, and payment information including credit cardnumber ("**Personal Information**"); and (2) **demographic information**, such as information about your gender, children, occupation, education level, and grades you work with ifyou are a professional educator ("**Demographic Information**"). We may collect this information through various forms and in various places on the Service, including accountregistration forms, contact us forms, at checkout when ordering products, or when you otherwise interact with the Service. To the extent we combine the non-**Personallyidentifiable Demographic Information** with the **Personal Information** we collect directly from you on the Service, we will treat the combined data as **PERSONAL INFORMATION** under thisPrivacy Policy.

**Phrase = 'Personal Information and Demographic Information'**

**Info:-**

I want to search the above Phrase in this text file. In this text file, those Phrases may be same to same or in with punctuation or in lower or upper or title or white space between words or without space or jumbled word.

**Requirement:-**
It returns output either those below phrases or position of those phrases or its return True or False.

Personal Information and Demographic Information,
Personal Demographicinformation,
Personal Information,
demographic information,
Demographic Information,
Personallyidentifiable Demographic Information,
Personal Information,
PERSONAL INFORMATION

Comment: You should use RegEx. Try the re library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

import re
matches = re.findall(r'((?: personal|demographic)[\s\w]*information\b)', text, flags=re.I)
```

Output:

```
['Demographic Information',
 ' Personal Demographicinformation',
 'demographic information',
 'Demographic Information',
 'Demographic Information with the Personal Information',
 ' PERSONAL INFORMATION']
```